# Trending Topics Plugin

Tags: plugins

I am looking for a trending topics plugin as displayed on [techcrunch](http://www.techcrunch.com). I have searched alot to find the vertical displaying plugin. If anyone could help out, I would be very thankful.

### EDIT:

Here is a visual image of how it should look like.
[image]

Comment: As I understand it you're wanting a drop in plugin that does exactly what you want with no extra work and you're not finding it? Are those 'topics' BBPress threads? Categories? Tags? Twitter hashtags? More information needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by hot trends you mean the categories, you can list the categories with the most posts using this plugin:

http://searchwordpressplugins.com/plugin/most-popular-categories/

**Some styling work will be needed, but that is *unavoidable* no matter what plugin is used.**

Tech Crunch however uses tags not categories, so instead you can use this:

http://searchwordpressplugins.com/plugin/most-popular-tags/

Answer (score 0):

Would this not just a popular posts plugin? - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-popular-posts/

Comment: Thanks, but it is not what I am looking for. I have provided a visual image of what I want.